# Read/Write GPIO

Tags: gpio, arm, assembly

I wrote an assembly code for my Raspberry Pi to read an I/O with a button and switch an LED according to the state of the button. It seems that the I/O with the LED is toggling all the time and I don´t understand why.

My idea is to use conditional execution for setting the LED state, according to the state of the I/O with the button (pull up with button connecting to ground).

Where is the mistake?

```
_start:
@ Base adress for gpio controller
ldr r0, =0x20200000

@ Set GPIO 24 as output
mov r2, #0x01
lsl r2, #0x0C
str r2, [r0, #0x08]

@ Set GPIO 13 as input
mov r1, #0x00
str r1, [r0, #0x04]

mov r2, #0x01
lsl r2, #0x0D

Loop:
    @ Read GPIO 13
    ldr r1, [r0, #0x34]

    @ Check if the button is pressed
    tst r1, r2

    @ Clear the GPIO if the button is not pressed (GPIO 13 = 1)
    streq r2, [r0, #0x28]

    @ Set the GPIO if the button is pressed (GPIO 13 = 0)
    strne r2, [r0, #0x1C]

    b Loop
```

Comment: With physical buttons, you will probably need to implement some [debouncing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce).

Comment: The LED pin is toggeling all the time without pressing the button.

Comment: please provide the schematic diagram of your connections

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the solution. There were some coding issues.

This code is working now:

```
.section .init
    .globl _start

_start:
@ Base adress for gpio controller
ldr r0, =0x20200000

@ Set GPIO 24 as output
mov r2, #0x01
lsl r2, #0x0C
str r2, [r0, #0x08]

@ Set GPIO 13 as input
mov r1, #0x00
str r1, [r0, #0x04]

@ I/O masks
mov r2, #0x01
lsl r2, #0x0D

mov r3, #0x01
lsl r3, #0x18

Loop:
    @ Read GPIO 13
    ldr r1, [r0, #0x34]

    @ Check if the button is pressed
    tst r1, r2

    @ Clear the GPIO if the button is not pressed (GPIO 13 = 1)
    streq r3, [r0, #0x28]

    @ Set the GPIO if the button is pressed (GPIO 13 = 0)
    strne r3, [r0, #0x1C]

    b Loop
```